# React prevState uses this particular parenthesis syntax. What is it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My question isn't how to set state with using the previous state. Rather what these ( ) specifically are doing and if this pattern has a name, what is it?

```
this.setState(prevstate => ({ count: prevstate.count + 1}));
                           ^                             ^
```

Are they an example of de-structuring?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its kind of a trick.

As of arrow syntax one of the basic syntax is,

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements } 
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
```

Checkout: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Here, if u use curly braces with arrow function then its interpreted as func body.
So, with arrow func you cant directly return object, instead for example Your above example will look like this,

```
this.setState(prevstate => {
  return { count: prevstate.count + 1}
});
```

Yep, u have to do return.

To Avoid this, the trick is to just wrap it in a parentheses `(`... `)` to make it a expression, Not a func body 
And thus you don't have to return like that

Comment: @risingBirdSong dont forget to mark as answer & upvote if it helped

Answer (score 1):

This is shorthand for returning an object. It is the same as

```js
this.setState(prevstate => { 
  return {
    count: prevstate.count + 1
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions may have an implicit return instead of a function body, e.g.

```js
const add = (a, b) => a + b;
```

Without the parens the curlies would be interpreted as the function body instead of an object literal to be returned.